# binary problem about .gop and extern variable

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system, elf

I am trying to make a bare metal program(It may also be called as a toy operating system) which uses code like this:

hello1.c

```
int a = 4;
```

hello2.c

```
void func(){
    extern int a;
    //Some operation using a...
}
```

I use gcc to compile, and "objcopy -O binary" to convert elf file to binary file, using my own linker file and _start function. And I found that a in func() is 0.

I found that the compiler didn't update value of extern variable at compiling time. It updates the variable when running from linux's _start function, at dl_main. It updates .got section with the actual address of variable a. I want to change this but don't know how to do. I tried add -fno-pic and -fno-pie but make no sense.

Comment: More contents is required, you need to construct a "Minimal, Reproducible Example“ see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. All above are not seen to be enought to understand the entire problem.